# Is there an umbrella term for "inflation" and "deflation"?

Tags: programming

I am writing a software module that takes polygons and either inflates them or deflates them based on user input (i.e. if the user supplies `0.5` as input, the polygon is deflated to half of its size, whereas if they supply `1.5`. it is inflated to 150% of its size). I'm having trouble naming this module, because I want it to be obvious what it does, but the only name I can think of (`PolygonInflaterOrDeflater`) feels like too much of a mouthful, even for software lexicon. Maybe a bit redundant, somehow, too... Anti-redundant, if that's a thing). Furthermore, there are other parts of the software that are named according to its function, such as `attemptPolygonInflationOrDeflation` which I feel suffer from the same problem. Is there a term that would obviously cover "Inflation" and "Deflation" simultaneously? I'm racking my brain and I can't think of one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our help center says that choosing names for things in computer programs is out of scope for our site.

Comment: Well, when it comes to an umbrella you're either *opening* it or *closing* it.

Comment: 'Enlargement'. This is defined using scale factors less than one as well as greater than one. And even for negative scale factors.

Comment: Inflation and deflation are changes in the value of money.

Comment: @Xanne Amongst other things.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite so, including tires, ego . . .

Comment: The mathematical term you are after is dilation. The other affine transformations are rotation and translation.

Comment: I do not believe this is off topic. Although the OPs purpose is to use the name in a computer program, he is clearly asking about english usage for its own sake irrespective of its intent.

Answer (score 1):

**Resize**.  A polygon is two-dimensional and both inflation and deflation suggest 3-dimensions.  Resize covers everything, even n-dimensions.  So, in pseudo-code:

```
Polygon1.Resize(0.5); // Deflation
Polygon2.Resize(2.3); // Inflation
```